# Модальное окно на сайте

Tags: javascript

При нажатии на кнопку "Купить" появляется текст зелёными буквами (скриншот прикрепил). Нужно сделать так чтобы при нажатии появлялся не текст, а модальное окно в котором будет то что я напишу. Не понимаю как сделать... Текст берётся из js.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код:

```js
$(document).on('submit', '.add_product_form', function(e){ 
    e.preventDefault();

    var  cart_size = ( $(this).parents().find(".cart_size_product").val()!='') ? $('.cart_size_product').val() : 'œÛÒÚÓ';
    var  tid =  $(this).parents().find(".add-cart").data("id");
    if($('#cartAdded'+tid).length==0) 
    $(this).parents().find(".add-cart").parent().append('<span style="color:#40b87d;display:block" id="cartAdded'+tid+'"><br>Добавлено в корзину!<br> <ins><a href="/cart/oneclick/" style="color:#40b87d"><b>Перейти в корзину</b></a></ins></span>');
    else $('#cartAdded'+tid).html('<span style="color:#40b87d;display:block" id="cartAdded'+tid+'"><br>Добавлено в корзину!<br> <ins><a href="/cart/oneclick/" style="color:#40b87d"><b>Перейти в корзину</b></a></ins></span>');
 window.addedId=tid;
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/include/addtocart.php", 
        data: {idAjax:tid, cart_sizeAjax:cart_size}, 
       
        cache: false,
        dataType: "html",
     success: function(data) {  
          console.log(data);
          loadcart(); 
          setTimeout("$('#cartAdded'+window.addedId).detach()",15000);
     }
}); 

});
```

Код кнопки:

```html
<input type="submit" style="margin-top: 15px;" class="add-cart btn btn--has-icon-after cart__continue-btn" id="add-cart-view" value="КУПИТЬ" data-id="'.$row1["products_id"].'" >
```

Comment: https://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-message

Comment: @Igor спасибо, но не могу понять как реализовать...

Comment: там прямо-таки есть образец - "view source"

Comment: @Igor да, видел, но не могу понять как впихнуть в мой код js...

Comment: а где ваш html css код ?мне написать ответ с нулья?

Comment: @Избытоксусликов добавил код кнопки, а css нету, всё берётся с js...

Comment: то есть вам нужно чтобы при клике на эту кнопку появлялсья модальное окно ?правильно?

Comment: @Избытоксусликов да, верно, желательно чтобы окно было "резиновое" чтобы отображалось ровно и на моб. устройствах...

Answer (score 2):

Я реализовал с помощью *чистого JavaScript-а* очень простой пример.

И закомментил почти каждую строку.

Я думаю не осталось никаких проблем и вопросов не осталось как и куда надо внедрить модальное окно.Модальное окно вещь весьма примитивное **нельзя для него включать jQuery или Bootstrap в ваш проект**.

И совет старайтесь все делать без использования `jQuery`

```js
// Берем модалку
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

// Берем кнопку которое открывет окно
var btn = document.querySelector(".add-cart");

//Берем  <span> элемент которое закрывает модалку 
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// когда user кликает открыть модальное окно
btn.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "block";
}

// когда user кликает <span> (x), закрыть модалку
span.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "none";
}

// Когда user кликает в другом место кроме модалки закрыть окно
window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == modal) {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

```css
/* Фон модалки */
.modal {
    display: none; /* по умолчанию скрыты */
    position: fixed; /* неизменять */
    z-index: 1; /* должно быть наверху всех элементов */
    padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%; /* полная ширина */
    height: 100%; /* полная высота */
    overflow: auto; /* скролл авто если будет нужно */
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* задний цвет */
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* тут думаю ясно */
}

/* Модал контент */
.modal-content {
    background-color: #fefefe;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 20px;
    border: 1px solid #888;
    width: 80%;
}

/* Закрывающая кнопка */
.close {
    color: #aaaaaa;
    float: right;
    font-size: 28px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<input type="submit" style="margin-top: 15px;" class="add-cart btn btn--has-icon-after cart__continue-btn" id="add-cart-view" value="КУПИТЬ" data-id="'.$row1["products_id"].'" > 

<!-- Модалка -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">

  <!-- Контент модалки -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <span class="close">&times;</span>
    <p>Какой то текст внутри модалки..</p>
  </div>
  
</div>
```

Comment: Скажите, первые строки вставлять в js?

Comment: оберните все в одну  функцию и вставте в свой код И там редактируйте как вам угодно .И примите ответ нажав на кнопку галочки слева от ответа если если он решил вашу проблему конечно.

Comment: Не понимаю что мне нужно поместить в js файл...

Comment: А что здесь не понятно? Первый блок js, второй css, третий html. Пройдите хотя-бы базовые курсы по html+css+js и все поймёте

Comment: При добавлении кода в js перестает вообще работать всё...

Comment: Используйте приём проектирования модуля закройте мою функцию и добавьте в свой код. Если не знаете что такое приём проектирование модуля можете прочитать тут https://learn.javascript.ru/closures-module

Comment: можете дать свои данные?